# Using url-retrieve to fetch an https resource through an http proxy

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to install [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) at my workplace, where all traffic passes through a Squid proxy.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
(unless (require 'el-get nil t)
  (setq url-proxy-services '(("https" . "proxy.work.com:8080"))) ; if needed
  (url-retrieve
   "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
   (lambda (s)
     (end-of-buffer)
     (eval-print-last-sexp))))
```

As far as I can tell, this fails because [Squid doesn't support https through http](http://lists.xymon.com/oldarchive/2005/08/msg00220.html). (Squid returns `HTTP/501 Not Implemented`)

I can and will install el-get manually, but my curiosity has been piqued. How do browsers work around this?

Comment: How to install el-get manually? I came into the same problem.

Comment: Clone the git repository into ~/.emacs.d, add it to the path, and require it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can simply just retrieve the same file from http://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el as github offers both SSL and non-SSL interfaces to it's raw file service.